# "Error: Could not find or load main class ${start-class} spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Spring-Boot error after you try running the application as a jar.

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly because there are two main classes in your project and you have to activate one by either:
a. Deleting main classes so that you remain with only one main class. (how to identify classes with main() in IntelliJ--->>Use Edit->find in path then search for main() to easily identify classes with main methods)
b.go to your pom file and specify the Main class which you want to use.